# Why isn't Lucy Rippled away in Karma Chameleon

Tags: time-travel, timeless

In S1:E13 Karma Chameleon of [Timeless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeless_(TV_series)), only Rufus and Wyatt go back in time in an attempt to stop Wyatt's wife's killer from being born.

In earlier episodes, most clearly in S1:E1 (Pilot) and S1:E4 (Party at Castle Varlar), we have seen that the people who don't travel in time remember only the new timeline. Episode 4 has everyone discussing the best ever Bond film, that mirrored the Episode's plot and the Pilot has Lucy's sister being removed from existence, remembered by no-one except the central trio.

So, why does Lucy who was left behind on this trip not get updated to a version that always lived in the new timeline, and therefore forget her Sister who only ever existed in the pre-pilot timeline?

Comment: My bet is: this is one of the many inconsistencies of the show, which plot seldom tries to address the challenges of time-travel. I don't think there is any in-universe explanation.

Comment: @Evargalo I got a [Tumbleweed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed?userid=40437) badge for this question and 3 months later I get a comment and not even a pity upvote! You're killing me :)

Comment: I couldn't help but upvote your comment.

Comment: You get a +1 finally. Unfortunately some questions on less popular works get rather sidelined in favour of big names like Harry Potter, Star Wars, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

My impression was that the show was pretty consistent throughout its relatively short run in that, as you say, those who travel are protected from the changes to the timeline, while those who stay behind remember only the new timeline.

However, I think it's important to note that it's not simply the case that anyone who doesn't time travel is "reset" to only know the resulting timeline. I rather think that whoever doesn't participate *in a particular trip* is unaware of the particular changes resulting from that very trip.<sup>1</sup>

Now, what definitely ahppens after Wyatt's and Rufus's return is that the timeline they had departed from is changed (at the point where Wes Gilliam's father is killed) so Wes Gilliam (Jessica's presumed murderer) is never born. Wyatt and Rufus remember him from that old timeline, while non-time-travelling observers - let's use Denise Christopher as a representative example here - do not.

With the aforementioned mechanic in mind, I think there are two possible interpretations of how things work out for Lucy, neither of which has her forget about her sister, though:

- Either, the new timeline contains the Lucy from the original, pre-pilot timeline. In this case, she remembers Amy, but also Wes Gilliam (provided that she had known about him before, but that's irrelevant at that point). She didn't travel together with Wyatt and Rufus, *but* she originated from another timeline whose recent past had *not* been changed by Wyatt's and Rufus's travel.
- Or, the new timeline contains a Lucy that is the same as the Lucy from before Wyatt's and Rufus's trip, *but* whose own past had been changed in such a way that Wes Gilliam has never existed. This Lucy would still remember Amy, but not Wes Gilliam.

I presume it's the second option that is at work throughout the series, if only for the storytelling reason that option 1 would somehow make anyone impervious to timeline changes starting with their first time travel.

---

<sup>1</sup>: The effects of overlapping trips by the two time machines may be more complex, but are (luckily) beside the point here.

Comment: I like the idea, though it sounds very complicated for a universe to implement. It would go some way towards explaining the lack of butterfly effects, timeline changes in Timeless always seem pretty direct without knock on issues. Less for the universe to update.

Comment: @Jontia: It seems to me that the lack of butterfly effects are quite unrelated to this; indeed, I'd expect plenty more (at least subtle) changes after each trip, though the series convention seemed to be to keep these to a minimum. With that said, and based upon what we saw on the show, the mechanics I described seem to me like the most straightforward options that would not require some kind of an "intelligent" universe. Remember that the people outside the time machine are not "actively replaced" in any way once the past has changed; their personal history has simply evolved somewhat ...

Comment: ... differently, as has the entire history of the world, starting from the moment of the change.